# The getter 'instance' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAuth'

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use firebase auth in my flutter app and am running into the following error:

```
The getter 'instance' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAuth'.
```

Steps I followed:

1. via cli: `flutter pub add firebase_auth`
2. in signup.dart:

```
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

however, this is where I see the error. I haven't found literally anything on google that addresses this issue i.e. no indication that `FirebaseAuth.instance` is no longer supported. Could someone help me understand what is going wrong? Thank you!

[Edit] Adding pubspec.yaml below:

```
name: earl_v1
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.5 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.15.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.7.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: Take a look at example: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth/example

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your `pubspec.yaml` file

Comment: @MendelG, added! But now, all of a sudden it works. I have no idea why because I didn't change anything

Comment: @Hamed, thanks for the link! That was helpful. The odd thing is, if I copy + paste  the `main()` function as written in your linked example (i.e. `auth = FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: app)`), I receive the following error:  `Field 'auth' has not been initialized.` However, if I declare auth *before and outside* of `main()`, then it works without error. Any idea why this is? Thanks!

Comment: try `late final FirebaseAuth auth;` outside of `main` function and initial `auth` inside `main()` function. additionally, you may need to add `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` in the first line of main function.